# How to execute a cypress script in order to fetch the newly updated value in testdata.json file

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have created a script where I will generate a random word using this code.

```
    Alpha_Numeric() {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    
          cy.log("site name: ",text);
        return text;
      }
```

And store the value into testdata.json using this code

```js
        cy.readFile(filepath).then((obj)=>{
          obj.site=site_name;
          cy.writeFile(filepath,obj);
        })
```

During run time I will read this value from the json and use it in.

I will be following the same steps for 3 different testcases because the value which I have added once cannot be repeated.

The problem what I'm facing is for the first testcase the code is working properly and for the reaming two testcases what's happening is, in the json file the value of 'site' is updated but during run time the older value is fetched IDK why.

Can anyone resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem if you use `cy.fixture()` to read the file multiple time, this command is caching. It will only read from the disk once, there-after it will give the test the cached (old) value.

Instead of `cy.fixture()` you can use `cy.readFile()` each time the test needs to use the values from `testdata.json`.

See [fixture#Loaded-just-once](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Loaded-just-once)

> Please keep in mind that fixture files are assumed to be unchanged during the test, and thus Cypress loads them just once. Even if you overwrite the fixture file itself, the already loaded fixture data remains the same.
>
> If you wish to ***dynamically change the contents of a file*** during your tests, consider `cy.readFile()` instead.

See also [fixture#See-also](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#See-also)

> **See also**
> `.readFile()` for a similar command ***without caching*** and with builtin retryability

Answer (score 1):

You can also modify `testdata.json` on the fly, something like

```js
const { alphaNumeric } = require('my-funcs.js')

cy.fixture('testdata.json').then(data => {
  data.site = alphaNumeric();

  // test continues with new data
```

If you wish you can also avoid importing by creating a Custom Command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('alphaNumeric', () => {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    
          cy.log("site name: ",text);
        return text;
      })
```